# column calculation based on a value

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

using yfinance to get the below df, How do I calculate the "Day_Delta" column with +/-% delta from beginning day's Open_Value

```
symbol  Datetime                    Value_Type  Open_Value  Day_Delta
AAPL    2021-09-20 09:30:00-04:00   Close      143.839996    
AAPL    2021-09-20 10:00:00-04:00   Close      142.940002   
AAPL    2021-09-20 10:30:00-04:00   Close      142.750000            
AAPL    2021-09-20 11:00:00-04:00   Close      143.089905   
AAPL    2021-09-20 11:30:00-04:00   Close      142.490494
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected values for Day_Delta, please?

Comment: You can do it row by row, of course.  If you haven't seen this symbol on this date, save the base value.  Then set your new column to `(Open_Value - base) * 100 / Open_Value`

Comment: @TimRoberts: How do i create a column 'base' to perform the calculation?

Comment: `(df.Open_Value.pct_change() + 1).cumprod() * 100 - 100` ? I missed the `delta` part in my last comment.

Comment: Or @TimRoberts solution, which is much faster `(df.Open_Value - df.Open_Value[0]) * 100 / df.Open_Value[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Separate out the Datetime to 2 columns: Date and Time

   ```
    symbol  Date             Time       Open_Value
    AAPL    2021-09-20  09:30:00-04:00  143.800003
   ```
2. Sort and remove duplicate from 'symbol' and 'Date'

   ```
   stock_day_open = stock_data.sort_values(['symbol', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open_Value'], ascending[True, True, True, True])
   stock_day_open = stock_day_open.drop_duplicates(['symbol','Date'], keep='first')
   ```
3. merge to a new_df to add a column
4. Calculate the 'Day_Delta'

Comment: The main part of your question ("calculate the 'Day_Delta' column") remains vague.

Comment: well it was misunderstood from your part. you dont have to downgrade the question..